# refactor express app.js in multiple files

Tags: express, refactoring

I try to refactor my `app.js` file in multiple files based on their routes.

My problem: my routes have dependencies with two functions define at the beginning of my file :

```
const app = express()

const cognitoExpress = new CognitoExpress({
  region: '<some text>',
  cognitoUserPoolId: '<some text>',
  tokenUse: 'access',
  tokenExpiration: 3600000
})

let cachedDb = null

function isAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  let accessTokenFromClient = req.headers.authorization

  if (!accessTokenFromClient)
    return res.status(401).send('Access Token missing from header')

  cognitoExpress.validate(accessTokenFromClient, function (err, response) {
    if (err)
      return res.status(401).send(err)

    res.locals.user = response
    next()
  })
}

function connectToDatabase(uri) {
  if (cachedDb && cachedDb.serverConfig.isConnected()) {
    return Promise.resolve(cachedDb)
  }

  return MongoClient.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true })
    .then(client => {
      cachedDb = client.db('<some text>')
      return cachedDb
    })
}
```

And my routes are define like this:

```
app.get('/users', isAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  connectToDatabase(process.env.MONGODB_CONNECTION_STRING)
    .then((db) => {
      return db.collection('users').find().toArray()
    })
    .then(result => {
      return res.send(result)
    })
    .catch(err => res.send(err).status(400))
})
```

My question: How refactor my routes in multiples files with these 2 functions? Is there a way to export these functions?

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a file maybe config.js or middleware.js, anyone you'd like, then import and use them in your routes.